# Can i use a simpleType multiple Times?

Tags: xsd

I use this simpleType multiple times in my xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Is there a way to define it once and then use it multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. Just give it a name.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myType">
...
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element type="myType" .../>
```